# What skill set is needed to set up Solr or ElasticSearch?

Tags: search, solr, elasticsearch

Two clients of mine are evaluating setting up a search server, either Solr or ElasticSearch. We're wondering what programming languages (if any) and development environments are necessary to get the search servers running. Can it be done by people mostly familiar with front end technologies (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) or is more serious coding skill needed (e.g. understanding of multithreading/ advanced debugging/ other "pro-level" concepts)?

If only light programming skills are needed I'm playing with the thought of suggesting to set it up myself. I have very little Java knowledge but have basic understanding of C, ActionScript, Pascal and even [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) in addition to aforementioned front end technologies. I know basic search architecture from my time in [FAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Search_%26_Transfer) (an enterprise search vendor).

Best, Bjørn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a broad question but i'll try to give it a shot:

You don't need any programming language in particular. They're both stand alone servers which have API's which are addressable from any programming language.

- ElasticSearch has a really nice API that's JSON/REST based.
- SOLR's API is a lot more clunky, but also supports XML.

(If I have a choice I tend to go for ElasticSearch, unless there's a really specialized feature I need that's only in SOLR).

Getting up and running doesn't really require any knowledge of any programming language in particular.

The only time you NEED java is when you decide you end up needing custom plugins to SOLR/ElasticSearch itself.

You don't need any specific IDE's beyond those matching your programming language of choice.

When trying to figure out what's going on inside my elasitc search server I do like elastic search HEAD:

http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, this is quite a broad question, most likely get closed. But I'll give it a go too.

Both ElasticSearch and Solr are quite easy to get started with. They come as a zip/tar.gz archive that you can extract.

Both require JVM, so you need Java setup.

Once setup, playing with either is quite easy, you do not need any advanced programming skills to play around with it. Solr comes with an Admin UI page, that allows you to execute queries.

Elastic Search has clients as @Constantijin has pointed out. Elastic-head is an excellent choice.

You will need quite a detailed understanding of the Lucene ecosystem, its architecture, plugins etc. Given you have an understanding of another Search Engine, the concepts around indexing and text processing should be easy enough for you.

If you want to write something more advanced than the Admin UI, and you can use Javascript.

- You can use [AjaxSolr](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) for making ajax requests to your Solr instance
- For ElasticSearch, you can try using [Elastic.js](https://github.com/fullscale/elastic.js).

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is an open-source search engine built on top of Apache Lucene™, a full-text search-engine library. Lucene is arguably the most advanced, high-performance, and fully featured search engine library in existence today—both open source and proprietary.

However, Elasticsearch is much more than just Lucene and much more than “just” full-text search. It can also be described as follows:

A distributed real-time document store where every field is indexed and searchable

- A distributed search engine with real-time analytics
- Capable of scaling to hundreds of servers and petabytes of structured and
  unstructured data

I would like add more details regarding how to used ElasticSearch in php language check out - http://www.multidots.com/what-is-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

**[How to integrate ElasticSearch with PHP?][1]**

By using curl, you can use ElasticSearch with your favorite programming language. Here is the example of simple curl request with ElasticSearch.

**- PHP Sample Script:**

You can find PHP client api on github:

[https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php][2]

Check out Best Article on Elasticsearch - http://www.multidots.com/what-is-elasticsearch

Comment: Your links are broken - also please do not provide link only answers but post the example code here